# Sending data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, send

i have a build a javascript which does following:
Get content via ajax->php->sql and show it on index.php
after clicking the content there will be shown new content.

Now I want to have a function which sends data after content is clicked to a php which will do something in in the db. How can i create a function which will send data? Thank you!

This is my code which shows content:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function laden(){
$(function() 
{

$.ajax({                  
`usr_id`                    
  url: 'content/get.php',              


  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)         
  {
    var id = data[0];             
    var name = data[1];

    var count = data[3];


    $('#output').html('<div onclick="laden('+id+')" id="content"></div>');

  } 
});
```

}); 
    }
    `

Comment: Read up on this - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can send data to the callback script, specified in the URL, by including values in the jQuery.ajax `data` setting.  Depending on what type of request you're making, this data will either be included in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` global variables.  For example, to POST data to your callback script, you could do:

```
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'content/get.php',     
  type: 'post', // performing a POST request
  data : {
    data1 : 'value' // will be accessible in $_POST['data1']
  },
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)         
  {
    // etc...
  } 
});
```

For more information, please read up on the jQuery.ajax function's documentation at  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Dear Ethan, I'm using 3 browser : maxthon, mozilla, and spark browser but his method just working fine in maxthon. What's wrong? Can you tell me?

Comment: @HendryTanaka Can't tell without a code example, but I think you should post your own question if you'd like assistance.

Comment: No matter Ethan. [I found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189491/sending-data-to-php-via-ajax-is-not-working-in-every-browser?noredirect=1#comment41105515_26189491). Thanks for your attention.