# Debug variable sent by Jquery (AJAX) at PHP code at server

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a host server at a web-hosting and my PHP file is lodated in a folder at server. From my HTML form, I send some data using Jquery AJAX and I like to view all those variables in my PHP code at server side.
My Jquery AJAX code is as follow.

```
function sendtoServer() {

     $.ajax({
        url: "advertisementdatavalidationatserver.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#landedForm").serialize(), 
        success:  function(ret){

});
}
```

My PHP code at server is

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data['error'] = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if(!isset($_POST['purpose'])){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Purposeerror";
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['type'])){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Typeerror";
    }

    if ($_POST['type'] == "With_RC" || $_POST['type'] == "With_BrickNorcal") { 

        if ($_POST['stories'] == "Stories"){
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Storieserror";        
        }


        if ($_POST['bedrooms'] == "Bedrooms") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Bedroomserror";        
        }

        if ($_POST['bathrooms'] == "Bathrooms") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Bathroomserror";        
        }

    }

    if ($_POST['divs_states'] == "Division") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Divisionerror";        
    }

    if ($_POST['township'] == "Township") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Townshiperror";        
    }

    if ($_POST['price']=="") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Priceerror";        
    }else if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['price']) ) {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Priceinvalid";        
    } 

    if ($_POST['length']=="") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Lengtherror";        
    }else if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['length']) ) {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Lengthinvalid";        
    } 

    if ($_POST['width']=="") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Widtherror";        
    }else if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['width']) ) {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Widthinvalid";        
    }    

    if(!isset($_POST['haveaircon'])){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Airconerror";
    }

    if ($_POST['possession'] == "Possession") {        
            $data['error'] = true;
            $data['message'][] = "Possessionerror";        
    }

    if($_POST['date']==""){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Dateerror";
    }

    if($_POST['textarea'] == "Please enter additional information here..." || $_POST['textarea'] ==""){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Textareaerror";
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['agentowner'])){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Agentownererror";
    }

    if($_POST['name'] == ""){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Nameerror";
    }

    if($_POST['phone'] == ""){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Phoneerror";
    }else if((strlen($_POST['phone']) < 6) || !preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_POST['phone'])){
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Phoneinvalid";
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])){ 
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Emailrequired";
    }else if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['message'][] = "Emailinvalid";
    }

    if(!$data['error']){
        // No errors, save into database

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","thitsun_admin","z4iufn8n##");

        if (!$con)
        {
           $data['error'] = true;
           $data['message'][] = "Connectionerror";
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }else{

           mysql_select_db("thitsun_properties_database", $con);

           $purpose = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['purpose']);           
           $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
           $stories = NULL;
           $bedrooms = NULL;
           $bathrooms = NULL;
           if ($_POST['type'] == "With_RC" || $_POST['type'] == "With_BrickNorcal") { 
                $stories = intval($_POST['stories']);
                $bedrooms = intval($_POST['bedrooms']);
                $bathrooms = intval($_POST['bathrooms']);
           }
           $divs_states = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['divs_states']);
           $township = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['township']);
           $price = intval($_POST['price']);
           $length = intval($_POST['length']);
           $width = intval($_POST['width']);

           if($_POST['haveaircon'] == "yes")
               $haveaircon = "yes";
           else
               $haveaircon = "no";
           if($_POST['havetelephone'] == "yes")
               $havetelephone = "yes";
           else
               $havetelephone = "no";

           $possession = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['possession']);
           $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
           $textarea = null;
           if($_POST['textarea'] != "Please enter additional information here..." || $_POST['textarea'] != ""){ 
              $textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
           }

           $agentowner = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['agentowner']);
           $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
           $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
           $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

           $address = NULL;
           if($_POST['address'] != "Please key in full address if you are ok..." || $_POST['address'] != ""){ 
              $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
           }          

           $query = "INSERT INTO `thitsun_properties_database`.`registered_properties`(`id`, `purpose`, `type`, `num_stories`, `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `div_state`, `township`, `price`, `length`, `width`, `have_phone`, `have_aircon`, `possession`, `available_date`, `description`, `agentowner`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `submitteddate`) VALUES (NULL,'$purpose', '$type','$stories', '$bedrooms', '$bathrooms', '$divs_states', '$township', '$price', '$length', '$width', '$havetelephone', '$haveaircon', '$possession', '$date', '$textarea', '$agentowner', '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$address',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
   // `id`, `purpose`, `type`, `num_stories`, `bedrooms`, `bathrooms`, `div_state`, `township`, `price`, `length`, `width`, `have_phone`, `have_aircon`, `possession`, `available_date`, `description`, `agentowner`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, //`submitteddate`


    //'$purpose', '$type','$stories', '$bedrooms', '$bathrooms', '$divs_states', '$township', '$price', '$length', '$width', '$havetelephone', '$haveaircon', '$possession', '$date', '$textarea', '$agentowner', '$name', '$phone', '$email', //'$address',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           if(mysql_query($query,$con) or die("Insertion Failed:".mysql_error()))
           {
              if(mysql_affected_rows($con)!=1){
                 $data['error'] = true;
                 $data['message'][] = "Connectionerror";
              }
           }

            mysql_close($con);
        }

    }
}

// then echo the $data array you have built as JSON to use in jquery. 
//This will be what is returned in your AJAX request
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I like to debug all these variables like `$name, $email, $phone` before they are put into database. Of course, I can check once they are successfully saved into database. But in some cases, if they can't be saved into database, I need to check what are the value inside these variables.

All discussions said to use print, print_r or echo. I used them, but I don't see any output or frankly is no idea where to see those outputs. I checked in the console (F12), but nothing is there.

My query is I have PHP code in a .php file located in host sever. How can I view the variables sent via AJAX at PHP code?

Thanks

Comment: You have to look at your generated html, they are printed there. Call the php url from your browser and you will see the output.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['type']); die();` Do not do this in a prod environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between echo, print, and print\_r in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php)

Comment: Thats better, now people can see what you are trying to do

Comment: @Abdulla No its more complicated that that, he want to know how he can view the data provided on an AJAX call to a server script, so he can see what gets sent to the server on th server

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was just edited. Check hos edit. Thats y voted.

Comment: @DanielHigueras I know I can view at my HTML using alert or console.log. I just want to check at PHP side before logged into database. I had error saving into database (now solved), if there is a way to view at PHP code I can debug easily.

Comment: If you send variables via AJAX you can echo them in the PHP which will be returned via the AJAX call to the browser. [If you watch the request / response in the browser's console](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) you can see what was input. *Something* tells me that you're trying to do some sort of validation though - if so there are several sound established methods for doing this. You can also debug database issue using the error logs on your server if you're not showing errors.

Comment: @batuman I believe installing a debug extension like http://xdebug.org/ can help you debug your variables server side.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks yeah I'll change.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I agree, we can send back using Json to view the returned data from PHP code. I wonder is there any other way? I like to test what Kisaragi suggested below how it does.

Comment: It depends on where you want to do this. BUT, if you use the things I have described above, especially prepared statements, you shouldn't have the problems you're describing.

Comment: @Abdulla Its now quite a good concise question now, would you consider removing your DV and close flag now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is to write the output of a `print_r($_POST)` to a file on the server because as you say there is no console or window that you can see the data coming into the server script that services your AJAX call

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data['error'] = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    file_put_contents('somefilename.txt', print_r($_POST,true), FILE_APPEND);

    // your other code
```

Using the `FILE_APPEND` option will add each call to the end of your file so you can check changes made in the javascript(AJAX) code with each change you make there

Answer (score 1):

`print`, `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` and other print functions output to the viewport - in most cases, this will be the browser.

If your file `index.php` contains:

```
<?php echo "Hello, world!" ?>
```

visiting `//index.php` will show

> Hello, world!

Similarly, if executing via command line, such as `> php index.php` you'll see the output in the terminal directly.

---

**To see the differences between `print`, `print_r`, `echo` and `var_dump`, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php).**

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the first few lines of `advertisementdatavalidationatserver.php`:

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Open web tools (chrome F12 for example) 
 Click 'Network' tab. 
 Make ajax request. 
 Click reaponse. 
 The response will contain a dump of `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Let me test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that logs anything in the error log file of the current directory , if you like to log them in a certain directory just add it before the third argument of error_log

```
  <?php
    //example of usage
    _log("this is a string");
    _log(array("key",4));


    function _log($msg)
    {
        if(is_string($msg))
        {
            error_log("\n".$msg,3,"error_log");
        }
        else
        {
            error_log("\n".print_r($msg,true),3,"error_log");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A print intitiated by PHP is interpreted by a webserver like Apache, Nginx, ... . For example you have the file `index.php` with the following content:

```
<html>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <body>
    <?php
      print("Hello, World!");
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and you add this file into the folder of your webserver, e.g. `/var/www/index.php` and you access your webserver with your browser, you can see the output of your PHP-prints.

Comment: Does it works, if solely PHP code in the server received data sent via AJAX?

Comment: You might want to look at this post, where AJAX posts to a PHP scripts are described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179620/sending-data-via-ajax