# How can I send a form via Ajax and php?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to submit some data via Ajax:

index.php:

```
<form>
  <input name="name" value="Frank"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    submit($form);  
});

function submit($form){
    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); 
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("post", "action.php");
    request.send(formdata);
    $.ajax({url: "action.php", success: function(result){
        $("#result").html(result);
    }});
}
</script>
```

action.php:

```
echo "hello ";
echo $_POST["name"];
```

My result:

```
hello
```

My expected result:

```
hello Frank
```

Comment: Is the contents of `$form[0]` what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Henders The content of the form

Comment: why are you doing xmlhttprequest and .ajax? Choose one or the other, not both. you're doing **TWO** ajax calls there. and on the .ajax version, you're sending a blank body to the server. and for the xmltttprequest you don't bother processing the response at all. you do a call and then forget it exists.

Comment: @MarcB Oh ok, I will check this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data via AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179620/sending-data-via-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
function submit($form){
    $.ajax('action.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Working very well! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mixing jquery ajax with normal ajax, you go wrong. Just stick with jquery ajax.

HTML Form and give your input an id:

```
<form>
  <input name="name" id="name" value="Frank"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



 $(function() {
         $(".submit").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var name = $("#name").val();
         var dataString = 'name='+ name;    
        if(name==''){
           alert('Name is blank');
           $("#name").focus();
        } else {
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
               url: "action.php",
              data: dataString,
           success: function(data){
               $("#result").html(data);
          }
         });
       }
       return false;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use FormData API then this is what you need to do:

```
<script>
 var formdata= document.querySelector("form");
 var data = new FormData(formdata);
 $.ajax({url: "action.php",data:data, success: function(result){
    $("#result").html(result);
}});

</script>
```